# Create a SVN retrocompatible repository

Tags: svn

on my osx leopard i've just installed svn, version 1.6.2 (r37639).
But some of my developer tool such as Zend Studio, etc are not compatible with the repository create by this subversion version. Are there some svnadmin options that I can use to make it works?

Comment: You can install older version of SVN or upgrade your tools.

Comment: What kind of tools? Administrative? Because all 1.x clients should be compatible with all 1.x servers - http://subversion.tigris.org/faq.html#interop.

Comment: I need to keep the version 1.6 for other project.
When I try to add my repo i've got the following error "Expected FS format '2'; found format '4'"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use  **file://** protocol, you cannot use an older client than the one you used while creating the repository. However, if you use **apache/webDAV**, or **svnserve** you should be able to access the newer repository.

svnserve is very easy to setup basically it is just:

```
svnserve -d -r </REPO/ROOT>
```

You can also install Subversion 1.5 and Subversion 1.6 on your machine. Then you just have to adapt your path via script so that you can user either 1.5 or 1.6

Comment: I hoped to use the file:// protocol because the repository is in the same machine. But it's ok i will try to use svnserve.
Thanks